# GridView, Al presionar la siguiente pagina desaparecen todas páginas

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Tengo un `GridView(gridPrestamosMes)` con la paginación activada. 
También el evento:

```
protected void gridPrestamosMes_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridPrestamosMes.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    }
```

creado al igual que:

```
protected void gridPrestamosMes_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetPaging();
        }
```

Por último tengo un método llamado SetPaging(). El cual lo uso para la paginación personalizada:

```
private void SetPaging()
        {
            GridViewRow row = gridPrestamosMes.BottomPagerRow;
            int alphaStart = 1;

            for (int i = 1; i < gridPrestamosMes.PageCount; i++)
            {
                LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
                btn.CommandName = "Página";
                btn.CommandArgument = i.ToString();

                if (i == gridPrestamosMes.PageIndex + 1)
                {
                    btn.BackColor = Color.Snow;
                    btn.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                }

                btn.Text = "Página " + alphaStart.ToString();
                btn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                btn.ToolTip = "Página " + i.ToString();
                alphaStart++;
                PlaceHolder place = row.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;
                place.Controls.Add(btn);

                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = " ";
                place.Controls.Add(lbl);
            }
        }
```

Todo funciona bien, pero el problema surge cuando selecciono la página 2, ya que al presionarla desaparecen todas las páginas:

[image: al cargarlo por primera vez funciona todo correcto]

[image: Al seleccionar la pagina 2 desaparecen las paginas]

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas Francisco,
En el evento `gridPrestamosMes_PageIndexChanging`debes recargar de nuevo el `GridView`.

Pongamos un ejemplo:

```
protected void gridPrestamosMes_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridPrestamosMes.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        LoadGrid();
    }
```

Donde `LoadGrid()`debe ser la función que se encarga de leer los datos y añadirlos al grid.

Espero que te ayude. Un saludo

Comment: añadí la siguiente línea: 

protected void gridPrestamosMes_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridPrestamosMes.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gridPrestamosMes.DataBind();
    }

pero siguen sin aparecer las demás páginas

Comment: Pero recargas el grid?

Comment: disculpa, como lo recargo?